# ArcGIS Time Slider - show hourly data only

Tags: arcgis-desktop, timeslider

I have point data that shows incidents in the years from 2011 to 2015 and it includes the specific time an incident occurred.

I would like to use the time slider functionality in ArcGIS Online to show the incidents that occur in each hour over a period of 24 hours.

For example: I would like it to show all incidents that occurred between years 2011 - 2015 between 13:00 - 14:00, 14:00 - 15:00, 15:00 - 16:00 etc.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

- The first step is to upload a feature with a time field.
- Then, ensure that the Time Settings are enabled and pointing to the correct field and date range

[image: Time Settings]

[image: Detailed Time Settings]

- Then, open a web map and add in the layer
- Click on the layer properties [...] and Enable Time Animation

[image]

- Finally, adjust the time settings to specify the date range and intervals

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this it is very helpful - the only thing is I would like to display the data in 1 hour intervals I think but the smallest time period I am given is weeks. I've seen a similar AGOL map which uses hours, so I am wondering if it might be my time format that is incorrect. Can you confirm how the time field should be formatted please? Or whether there is another solution?

Comment: I would need to do some digging, but its possible that your options for intervals (weeks, months,years) change dependent on the range of the data. For example, it wouldn't allow you to choose "hours" for a date range of 40 years. Try significantly limiting down the total range, and see if that works?

Comment: Take a look here under the [Time Display section](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-time.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_546F05D22ED14F468B19C4EAF0F4AFA9), specifically bullet #2.